# How to access multiple values of a key in dictionary in awk?

Tags: dictionary, unix, awk, bioinformatics, bed

So I am writing code in awk/bash. I have two files, the first of which is in the following format:

```
chr1_2376428_A_T
chr1_5465765_T_A
chr1_8958392_C_G
....
chrM_237426_C_G
```

This file spans all chromosomes and has multiple samples per chromosome. Now my second file is a gene annotation file, which has the following format:

```
chr1 HAVANA Exon 13642 13859 ....
chr1 HAVANA START_CODON 13642 13859 ....
....
```

I want to search whether values from file 1 fall in between any regions that are depicted by the start ($4) and end ($5) coordinates in the annotation file, given that the chromosomes match.

Sample Text Files:

```
echo -e chr1_2376428_A_T"/n"chr1_5465765_T_A"/n"chr1_8958392_C_G"/n"chr1_9542312_T_G > coordinates.txt

echo -e chr1"\t"HAVANA"\t"Exon"\t"13642"\t"13859"\n"chr1"\t"HAVANA"\t"START_CODON"\t"13642"\t"13859"\n"chr1"\t"HAVANA"\t"Exon"\t"5465750"\t"5465810"\n"chr1"\t"HAVANA"\t"gene"\t"6465750"\t"6465810"\n"chr1"\t"HAVANA"\t"Exon"\t"8958350"\t"8958461"\n" | gzip -c > gencode.v34.annotation.gtf.gz
```

I used the following code:

```
    zcat gencode.v34.annotation.gtf.gz | awk -v File=/pathto/Coordinates.txt 'BEGIN{comm="cat "File; while(comm|getline){split($1,a,"_");dict[a[1]]=a[2];}}{if ($1 in dict){if (dict[$1]>$4 && dict[1]<$5){print $1"_"dict[$1]"_"$3}}}'
```

The problem here is that the results I get for each chromosome are the last possible sample per chromosome, which made me think that only the last value of the key (chromosome number) is being compared and/or only being recorded. How can I test this for all values for a key?

Current outcome:

```
None
```

Expected outcome:

```
chr1_5465765_Exon
chr1_8958392_Exon
```

Thank you

---

EDIT: here is the above awk code pretty-printed by `gawk -o-` to be legible:

```
BEGIN {
        comm = "cat " File
        while (comm | getline) {
                split($1, a, "_")
                dict[a[1]] = a[2]
        }
}

{
        if ($1 in dict) {
                if (dict[$1] > $4 && dict[1] < $5) {
                        print $1 "_" dict[$1] "_" $3
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output, and code all formatted as Code Blocks (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Read [ask] and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples of good questions.

Comment: And please don't cram all of your code onto 1 line and then ask other people to read it. Make it as easy as possible for people to help you, including writing your code on multiple lines with appropriate indenting to be easily readable. I added code like that for you so you can see the difference in clarity.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases. For example, use [`bedtools`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), specifically `bedtools intersect`. It can be easily installed, for example using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html). You need to convert your format (`chr1_2376428_A_T`, etc) into `bed` or `vcf` first.

Comment: If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/), both of which deal with bioinformatics.

Comment: Related: [Using bedtools intersect with custom txt files](https://www.biostars.org/p/9567758/)

Comment: please update the question to insure: *a)* sample data from both files, *b)* samples that match and that do not match, *c)* the expected output and *d)* a textual description of how you're matching the data between files (not everyone reading this question is going to know which parts of the data represent *chromosomes*, *genes* and/or *regions*) so please consider describing the match in terms of fields, substrings, and literal values (eg, take a pair of matching lines and explain which parts of each line 'match')

Comment: the latest update shows two different sets of input; please update the question to insure we have a single set of inputs (that correspond with the expected output)

Comment: what's the expected max size (MBytes) of both files?  this could have an impact on the amount of memory needed by possible solutions

Comment: first 2 lines of the 2nd file start with `chr1` and have the same range `13642 13859`; what, if any, significance do we give to the differences `HAVANA Exon` vs `HAVANA START_CODON`?

Comment: Please get rid of the elipsis (`....`s) in your sample input/output to simply give us some text files we can copy/paste to test with as-is. Actually those might not be your sample input as I see you also have a couple of `echo` lines that you say are sample input. Are those `/n`s in the first one supposed to be `\n`s which some versions of awk would interpret as newlines? Pleases simplify this for us and just show 2 textual sample input files + 1 textual expected output file given that input. And get rid of the zipping and unzipping stuff, it's completely irrelevant and just adds clutter.

Answer (score 1):

- `array[key]=value` only allows a single value per key - it is overwritten whenever a new value is set (ie. each `dict[a[1]] = a[2]`)
- `dict[1]` seems to be a typo later in the script

---

Using a bioinformatics-specific tool such as bedtools, as mentioned by @timur-shtatland in the comments, is to be preferred. However, a naive SQL solution with [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org) could be:

```bash
$ cat >sqlite-commands <<'EOD'
    create table a (chr, v2, tag, start, end);
.separator \t
.import annotations_file a
    create table b (chr, idx, v3, v4);
.separator _
.import samples_file b
    select b.chr, b.idx, a.tag
        from a join b on a.chr = b.chr
        where a.start < b.idx and b.idx < a.end;
EOD
$ cat -A annotations_file
chr1^IHAVANA^IExon^I13642^I13859$
chr1^IHAVANA^ISTART_CODON^I13642^I13859$
chr1^IHAVANA^IExon^I5465750^I5465810$
chr1^IHAVANA^Igene^I6465750^I6465810$
chr1^IHAVANA^IExon^I8958350^I8958461$
$ cat samples_file
chr1_2376428_A_T
chr1_5465765_T_A
chr1_8958392_C_G
chr1_9542312_T_G
$
```

Then:

```
$ sqlite3 '' <sqlite-commands
chr1_5465765_Exon
chr1_8958392_Exon
$
```

I understand passing `''` as the database uses a temporary file and allows processing data that won't fit in memory.

---

To load data from a compressed file without decompressing to disk, you could use a fifo:

```
$ mkfifo annotations_fifo
$ zcat annotations_file.gz >annotations_fifo &
```

and use the name of the fifo (ie. `annotations_fifo`) in the sqlite import meta-command. (Remember to delete the fifo afterwards.)

Or if using bash and linux, perhaps use process redirection:

```
$ sqlite3 '' <sqlite-commands 4< <(zcat annotations_file.gz)
```

and use `/proc/self/fd/4` as the filename in the import meta-command: